# One table or Two tables to store Forum's threads and Posts?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, normalization, forum

I am building forum site with ASP.net and DB is MYSQL.

as you all know users can start a thread and others can reply to it.

So here is the table that I implemented.

```
CREATE TABLE `a_post` (
  `post_id_pk` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `is_thread` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `parent_thread_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `short_description` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `category_id_fk` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id_fk` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 ......
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

So I am using one table to store both threads and posts. This approach is working fine. Normally thread count is smaller than posts count. Or else I can implement two tables to do is. One is to store threads and another one is to store comments with the corresponding thread Id.

What is best? One table or managing two tables?

I want an answer with performance wise. People who did forum systems. You are most welcome here.

Answer (score 0):

One thread can have multiple posts and by that you might consider having two table, one for threads and one for posts.

also remember that, duo to microsoft naming conventions table field should be pascal case. so by that i suggest to change you schema to below:

**Table [Threads]**

```
ID int
CreatedBy int
CreatedOn DateTime
Title nvarchar
CategoryID int
...
```

**Table [ThreadPosts]**

```
ID int
ThreadID int
CreatedBy int
CreatedOn DateTime
Body nvarchar
...
```

by doing this you avoid data duplication, because for example when someone send a post on a thread you don't have a category_id to fill, and the field left empty. that might be the performance issue on larger systems.

consider you want to get all the posts of a thread. its so easy with two tables :

```
var query = from thread in db.Threads
            join posts in db.ThreadPosts on thread.ID equals posts.ThreadID
            where thread.ID == threadID
            select new ThreadFullModel(){
                 Thread = thread,
                 Posts = posts
            };
```